# How to get this bedroom window to lock?

Tags: windows, window-frame

In a rental I have this bedroom window that is very strange. It is the kind that opens sideways. However, BOTH sides of the window move. As a result, I cannot figure out how to get the window to lock. Even if I were to place a wooden rod on the inside to prevent one side of the window from opening, the other side can simply be opened from the outside.

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJl1D.jpg

It appears that both sides of the window are in a separate groove in the window frame. Bugscreen is in its own groove but was removed for the video demonstration.

There are locks on both sides of the window but they do not work with each other. In other words, I cannot pull down the lever when the two locks meet.

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi7wR.jpg

Is it possible to get this window to lock or has it been installed improperly? Is this something I can do (I love DIY but no experience with windows) or should I get the landlord to take care of it? What is involved in fixing it?

I am worried since I have some valuables in the house and no way of locking the window.

Thank you.

Comment: @crip659 you are right, it is possible to get it lock. They were not fully closed. I think that I am just somewhat puzzled by this window since both sides open. I have never seen that. It also makes it hard to fully close the window since one side will open slightly if I slam the other shut.

Answer (score 4):

Almost any window latch requires that the sash(es) be fully closed before it'll engage.

Clean thoroughly, then use some silicone spray lube to lessen friction in the slide channels. If both sashes are fully closed the latch should engage cleanly.

However, in some cases warpage or age result in the sashes being spaced from each other as well. It may then be necessary to flex the inner sash outward to bring the two closer. You should be able to see whether this is necessary as you work the latch.

It ain't rocket surgery, as they say. Just get things lined up properly and stop banging things around. You'll crack something. :)

P.S. You have "double slider" windows. Sliders operate horizontally, and "double" because both sashes are operable.

Comment: Thanks, glad we got this figured out. I'm not really slamming anything very hard. Even gently opening one side of the window causes the other side to move slightly. In order to lock it, I needed to basically spread both sides apart (using both arms simultaneously). Then the lock engages with little resistance.

Comment: The weather stripping to seal between the windows might be dragging a bit.  As @isherwood mention some silicone spray might help along top and bottom frames there also.